# JPA/Hibernate - one-to-many list vs set optimization

Tags: list, hibernate, jpa, set, one-to-many

I have a simple one-to-many bidirectional association between Account (one) <--> Transaction (many)

```
@Entity
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
    private List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
@Entity
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID")
    private Account account;


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Transaction that = (Transaction) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, that.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }
}
```

The account (ID = 1) already has one transaction. And, I'm adding adding another transaction to the account. The block of code runs within the context of a transaction. All assertions pass:

```
        execute(entityManager -> {
            Account account = entityManager.find(Account.class, 1L);
            //assertThat(account.getTransactions().size(), is(1));

            Transaction t1 = new Transaction();
            t1.setTitle("Buy veggies");
            t1.setAmount(100);
            account.getTransactions().add(t1); // ###
            t1.setAccount(account);
            entityManager.persist(t1);
            //assertThat(account.getTransactions().size(), is(2));
        });
```

Note the line marked **###**, where the many side of the collection is loaded. I expected Hibernate to issue a SELECT on the 'Transaction' entity but it didn't. I'm including the logs below:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        account0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        account0_.initial_balance as initial_2_0_0_,
        ...
    from
        account account0_ 
    where
        account0_.id=?
17:06:22.970 [main] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        transaction
        (id, account_id, amount, title) 
    values
        (null, ?, ?, ?)
17:06:22.973 [main] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
17:06:22.973 [main] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [DOUBLE] - [100.0]
17:06:22.973 [main] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [Buy veggies]
```

At the end of the transaction, I verified the integrity of the data and all looks fine. The following assertion (run a new transaction context) passed:

```
    execute(entityManager -> {
        Account account = entityManager.find(Account.class, 1L);
        assertThat(account.getTransactions().size(), is(2));
    });
```

Could someone please explain why the account.getTransactions().add(t1) did not trigger a sql SELECT? Is this Hibernate's optimization or am I missing anything?

To add to the confusion, I changed the collection to Set (everything else remains the same as before).

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
    private Set<Transaction> transactions = new HashSet<>();
```

And now, I noticed what I expected in the logs - There was indeed a sql SELECT issued when account.getTransactions().add(t1) was called:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        account0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        account0_.initial_balance as initial_2_0_0_,
        ...
    from
        account account0_ 
    where
        account0_.id=?
17:09:23.056 [main] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
Hibernate: 
    select
        transactio0_.account_id as account_4_6_0_,
        transactio0_.id as id1_6_0_,
        transactio0_.id as id1_6_1_,
        transactio0_.account_id as account_4_6_1_,
        transactio0_.amount as amount2_6_1_,
        transactio0_.title as title3_6_1_ 
    from
        transaction transactio0_ 
    where
        transactio0_.account_id=?
17:09:23.057 [main] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        transaction
        (id, account_id, amount, title) 
    values
        (null, ?, ?, ?)
17:09:23.059 [main] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
17:09:23.059 [main] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [DOUBLE] - [100.0]
17:09:23.059 [main] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [Buy veggies]
```

hibernate-core 5.4.12.Final in spring-boot 2.2.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding to a List, the current entries don't matter, if it's a Set you have to load the entries so that you can verify that you wouldn't try adding a duplicate value. The default `FetchType` of `@OneToMany` is `FetchType.LAZY`, hence the missing select statement. Accessing the List entries triggers a fetch.

Comment: Thank you. That helped.